# Combinatorics of groupings

Tags: co.combinatorics

Middle schoolers line up before school.  There are $N$ students in each of 6th, 7th and 8th grades.  So there are $\left(\begin{array}{c} 3N\cr N\ N\ N\end{array}\right)$ possible line-ups.

The younger kids are supposed to be first, so e.g. if $N=2$ then the line-up 887766 is the best, whereas $667788$ is the worst.

We'll score a line-up as follows.  The worst line-up (as above) gets score $0$.  To evaluate a line-up we swap kids until we arrive at the worst line-up, keeping track of a tally as follows:  add $1$ point when a $7$ passes right of a $6$, an $8$ passes right of a $7$, or a $6$ passes right of an $8$; subtract $1$ for the other swaps between different grades.

*Question:  how many line-ups of a given score are there?*

For example, the line-up $887766$ is put into position $667788$ by first moving each of the two $8$'s to the right, each contributing a tally of $2-2=0,$ thus arriving at $776688$ (with score $0$ so far).  Then we move the two $7$'s to the right, picking up $2\times 2 = 4$.  This score of $4$ is best for $N=2$.

In general, I think the scores fall in-between $0$ and $N^2$, and the number with score $k$ will be equal to the number with score $N^2-k.$  But what is that number!?

Comment: Consider the value $T:=\sum ix_i$, where $x_i$ is the grade of the $i$-th from the left student minus 6. It increases by 1 after each move, so what you looking for is the number of sequences with prescribed $T$. In other words, you look for a coefficient of $t^m x^Ny^Nz^N$ in $(x+ty+t^2z)^{3N}$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Not quite. OP's score function can decrease when 8 goes right of 6.

Comment: Total scores (over all line-ups) for $N=1,2,\dots$ are $$3, 180, 7560, 277200, 9459450, 308756448, \dots$$ which is not in the OEIS.

Comment: Actually, the numbers of line-ups with scores $0$ to $N^2$, for $N = 1, 2, 3, 4,$ look like the following refinements of the multinomial coefficients 6, 90, 1680 and 34650:
$[3, 3],$ $[6, 21, 36, 21, 6],$ $[9, 27, 108, 264, 432, 432, 264, 108, 27, 9]$, and $[12, 36, 108, 336, 870, 2016, 4041, 6252, 7308, 6252, 4041, 2016, 870, 336, 108, 36, 12].$

Comment: @EricZaslow: Here are counts for $N=5,6$:

    `[15, 45, 135, 330, 900, 2115, 4710, 10230, 21195, 40290, 69423, 102780, 126210, 126210, ...]`
and
    `[18, 54, 162, 396, 918, 2160, 4788, 9990, 20250, 40563, 79272, 149769, 276054, 491886, 830196, 1299720, 1840536, 2293326, 2473020, 2293326, ...]`

Comment: The generating polynomial for the number of line-ups can be obtained from [this generalization of Gaussian q-binomial coefficient](https://mathoverflow.net/q/446914/7076) as $x^{N(N-1)/2} f_{N,N,N}(x,x,x^{-1})$.