# 3D generalization of Gaussian q-binomial coefficient

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, binomial-coefficients, q-analogs, multiset

It is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#Inversions) that the coefficient of $q^t$ in Gaussian binomial coefficient $\binom{m+n}m_q$ equals the number of permutations of the multiset $\{0^m, 1^n\}$ with $t$ inversions.

> Is there a closed formula for the polynomial $f_{m,n,k}(q_{01},q_{02},q_{12})$, where the coefficient of $q_{01}^{t_{01}} q_{02}^{t_{02}} q_{12}^{t_{12}}$ equals the number of permutations of the multiset $\{0^m, 1^n, 2^k\}$ with $t_{ij}$ inversions formed by elements $i,j\in\{0,1,2\}$?

Clearly, we should have the following specializations:
$$\begin{cases}
f_{m,n,k}(1,1,1) = \binom{m+n+k}{m,\ n,\ k}, \\
f_{m,n,k}(q,1,1) = \binom{m+n+k}k\binom{m+n}m_{q}, \\
f_{m,n,k}(1,q,1) = \binom{m+n+k}n\binom{m+k}m_{q}, \\
f_{m,n,k}(1,1,q) = \binom{m+n+k}m\binom{n+k}n_{q}, \\
f_{m,n,k}(1,q,q) = \binom{m+n}m\binom{m+n+k}k_{q}, \\
f_{m,n,k}(q,1,q) = \binom{m+k}m\binom{m+n+k}n_{q}, \\
f_{m,n,k}(q,q,1) = \binom{n+k}n\binom{m+n+k}m_{q}, \\
f_{m,n,k}(q,q,q) = \binom{m+n+k}{m,\ n,\ k}_{q}.
\end{cases}
$$

[This question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/125846) may be relevant.

Comment: Well at least we can say $f_{m,n,k}(q,q,q) = \binom{m+n+k}{m,n,k}_q = \binom{m+n+k}{m}_q\binom{n+k}{n}_q \binom{k}{k}_q = \frac{[m+n+k]_q!}{[m]_q![n]_q![k]_q!}$. The proof is simple, same as showing multinomial is product of binomials: first choose the position of the $0$'s, then the $1$'s, then the $2$'s. See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1940045

Comment: @SamHopkins: Indeed, thanks! I've added this specialization to the question.

Comment: I note that every one of the 125 polynomials $f_{m,n,k}(q_{01},q_{02},q_{03})$ with $(m,n,k) \in [1,5]^3$ is irreducible.

Comment: Another, belated, comment. In the same way that the binomials (and $q$-binomials) are related to the Grassmannian, the multinomials with three parameters $\binom{m+n+k}{m,n,k}$ are related to 2-step flag varieties. So your polynomial could be related to 2-step flag varieties. Note that while they do not behave quite as nicely as Grassmannians, more is known about 2-step flag varieties than general flag varieties.